# Calling web service api

Tags: angularjs, json, api, service, factory

i am trying to fetch web service api but i am not able to display 
anything, i am new to angularjs please help me.
i have copied my controller and factory code which i am using.

Controller

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'fetchService', function($scope, fetchService){
    $scope.countries = fetchService.get();
}]);
```

service

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.factory('fetchService', ['$http', function($http){
    return{
        get: function(){
            return $http.get('api/data4.json').success(function(response){
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `fetchService.get()` is asynchronous (a promise returned by `$http`), so you have to use a `.then()` like so:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'fetchService', function($scope, fetchService){
    fetchService.get()
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.countries = response;
        });
}]);
```